# Widening primitive conversions literature

Tags: java, jls

I am reading the specification of the Java language, about the conversions of Assignments and I was trying to obtain the basic rules and there is some literature that confuses me a lot. There are some publications that say:

```
 Integer s11 = (short)7;
```

require a widening primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion. This is not a permitted conversion. I understand the compilation error and the contexts of the assignments. But really is a widening primitive conversion? 
I understand as follow:
      Integer <- Short <- short <- int
I see the widening between Integer and Short. or am I confused?

Comment: It's not: Integer <- Short <- short <- int, it's: Integer <- int <- short <- int and the widening is:  int <- short

Answer (score 3):

A widening primitive conversion is a conversion from one **primitive** type to another **primitive** type. In your example, the required widening primitive conversion is from `short` to `int`.

That widening primitive conversion is required in order for the following boxing conversion (from `int` to `Integer`) to be possible.

If you break the expression into two assignments, the type conversions would be clearer:

```
int s11 = (short)7; // widening primitive conversion from short to int
Integer i11 = s11; // boxing conversion from int to Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is widening followed by auto-boxing, i.e. `int <- short` followed by `Integer <- int`